# Storing contents of a text file in 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file as follows:

```
id1, 0, 0, 0
id2, 0, 0, 0
id3, 0, 0, 0
```

I want to store this data in an array but I also need each data to be an induvidual element in the corresponding line's array.
So the output should look like this:

```
[["id1", 0, 0, 0], ["id2", 0, 0, 0], ["id3", 0, 0, 0]...]
```

```
data= "data.txt"
dataArray= []
file = open(data, 'r')
contents=file.read()
file.close()
lines= contents.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    dataArray.append(line)
```

I couldn't find a way to split the string and store the data after this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a single space between every element of the line you can just change your `for` loop as -

```
for line in lines:
    dataArray.append(line.split(", "))
```

Here the `line` is further split on basis of `,` followed by a space. The split will return a list itself.

If that is not the case (I mean if there are non-uniform spaces) then you can just combine `split()`, `strip()` and list comprehension like this -

```
for line in lines:
    dataArray.append([e.strip() for e in line.split(',')])
```

Here strip is required because after `split()` the individual element of the output of split may contain space before or after it.

If you need the numbers to be converted as int, then further modify it to -

```
for line in lines:
    dataArray.append([int(e) if e.strip().isnumeric() else e.strip() for e in line.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is in csv format which is supported by python:

```
(sos_config) ~/wk/cliosoft/projects/sos_config $ ipython
Python 3.9.4 (default, Apr  9 2021, 01:03:21) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.23.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import csv

In [2]: !cat /tmp/data.csv
id1, 0, 0, 0
id2, 0, 0, 0
id3, 0, 0, 0

In [3]: with open('/tmp/data.csv') as f:
   ...:     reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:     data_array = [row for row in reader]
   ...: 

In [4]: data_array
Out[4]: 
[['id1', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0'],
 ['id2', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0'],
 ['id3', ' 0', ' 0', ' 0']]
```

Comment: To convert the text to numbers you can add `data_array = [[row[0], *[int(v) for v in row[1:]]] for row in data_array]` or do whatever other conversion you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this it'll take care of integer/strings separately and also new-line char -

```
with open(data, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines()
    result = [
        [
            int(k) if k.strip().isnumeric() else k
            for k in item.strip().split(',')
        ]
        for item in content
    ]
```